# App crashes on Button Press stating "Attempt to invoke virtual method"

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an android application which should opens an activity on button press, but when i click on itm the app crashes stating "Attempt to invoke virtual method". Here is my Code.

MainClass.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button Notify;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Notify = (Button)findViewById(R.id.notify);

        Notify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayPush.class);
                startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    }
```

My another activity class

DisplayPush.java

```
public class DisplayPush extends Activity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(DisplayPush.this,MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
  //  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification);

    TextView notification_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView notification_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");

    try{
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject(jsonData);
       // String title = notification.getString("push_hash");
        String message = notification.getString("alert");

      //  notification_title.setText(title);
        notification_message.setText(message);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong with the notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I have defined the acitivities in my manifest.
Here is the logcat.

```
03-21 06:51:35.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 06:51:35.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3042): Process: hasan.parsereceiveandshow, PID: 3042
03-21 06:51:35.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3042): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hasan.parsereceiveandshow/hasan.parsereceiveandshow.DisplayPush}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in log:

```
Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Because `extras` is `null`.

Not sending Bundle which contain `com.parse.Data` key with Intent which is used for starting `DisplayPush` Activity on Button Click.

> What should i edit in code ?

Send data with `com.parse.Data` key in Intent on `Notify` Button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayPush.class);
intent.putExtra("com.parse.Data","String text");
startActivity(intent);
```

And also add null check before getting values from Bundle:

```
if(extras !=null)
  if(extras.containsKey("com.parse.Data"))
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
```

And define `String jsonData;` globally as said in comments.

Comment: @penta: add `null` check and also use `extras.containsKey` for checking key is present in Bundle or not before accessing value

Comment: where should i type Bundle extras = intent.getExtras()...in my code

Comment: @penta: just after `Intent intent = getIntent();` line

Comment: @penta: which string not resolved? declare all strings globally and use in onCreate method

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that you're trying to call `getString` method on null reference. In `DisplayPush` you are getting `Bundle` object from intent which is null, because you didn't put any in your intent in `onClick` method in `MainActivity` class.